# Dll file in Bin folder can be downloaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I create a website using asp.net and after compiling the project the visual gives me a dll file in Bin folder .So i uploaded the file to my server in my company ,but my network administrator said to me ? your dll file can be downloaded and can be read by hackers ?!!!so i really confused ,I know the permission of the Bin folder can prevent to stolen by hackers ?But the administrator said to me :No it can be downloaded ?

Is it possible ?

If yes what should i do ?
So any idea i will be appreciate ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: Ask your administrator to show you how it can be done...

Comment: he just said to me you should use refelector method .

Comment: Again - get your administrator to *prove* it. I suspect he doesn't understand ASP.NET.

Comment: @user3391903 - I mean the 'download' part

Comment: I really was concern about this issue ,but thank you Jakub and Jon

Comment: The bin-ordner is not accessable from any client. Btw.: Using reflection is possible anywhere, be it bin or any other folder. The actual protection against this "attack" comes from the web-service that won´t allow you to access this directory so even reflection won´t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bin directory is protected and your webserver will also not accept requests for *.dll by default.

I would question your Administrator...

Comment: So you mean it is not possible ?

Comment: It is not possible by default